# Power iteration sign of eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I need to write a program which computes all eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors. I'd like to use power iterations method (I know that it's not good but it's really necessary).

my algorithm is:

1) find largest (absolute) eigenvalue\eigenvector by power iterations method

2) determine sign (positive or negative) of that found eigenvalue

3) recalculate initial matrix for finding next largest (absolute) eigenvalue\eigenvector

4) goto step 1)

My question is about step 2).
I have no idea how to determine sign of eigenvalue. It's important because algorithm does not work if sign is incorrect.
Could somebody help me???

P.S. for example:
I have the matrix
$$\begin{matrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        2 & 5 & 6 \\
        3 & 6 & 2 \\
        \end{matrix}$$
I'd like to find all eigenpairs. At first I use power iteration method and found that eigenvalue is 10.88 and eigenvector is {0.33 0.73 0.60}

I have no idea is found eigenvalue is positive or negative. I assume that is positive and recalculate my initial matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        2 & 5 & 6 \\
        3 & 6 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}
        0.33 & 0 & 0 \\
        0.73 & 0 & 0 \\
        0.60 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
        0.33 & 0.73 & 0.60 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\cdot10.88=\begin{pmatrix}
        -0.18 & -0.61 & 0.84 \\
        -0.61 & -0.75 & 1.24 \\
        0.84 & 1.24 & -1.95 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
After that I again use power iteration method and found that eigenvalue is 3.089.
Here is:
$$EigenvectorEstimation1=\begin{pmatrix}
        -0.18 & -0.61 & 0.84 \\
        -0.61 & -0.75 & 1.24 \\
        0.84 & 1.24 & -1.95 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        0.042 \\
        -0.12 \\
        0.12 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
$$EigenvalueEstimation1=\sqrt{0.042^2+(-0.12)^2+0.12^2}=0.178$$
$$EigenvectorNormalized1=\begin{pmatrix}
        0.042/0.178 \\
        -0.12/0.178 \\
        0.12/0.178 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        0.237 \\
        -0.68 \\
        0.69 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
$$EigenvectorEstimation2=\begin{pmatrix}
        -0.18 & -0.61 & 0.84 \\
        -0.61 & -0.75 & 1.24 \\
        0.84 & 1.24 & -1.95 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
        0.237 \\
        -0.68 \\
        0.69 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        0.95 \\
        1.22 \\
        -1.99 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
$$EigenvalueEstimation2=\sqrt{0.95^2+1.22^2+(-1.99)^2}=2.524$$
$$EigenvectorNormalized2=\begin{pmatrix}
        0.95/2.524 \\
        1.22/2.524 \\
        -1.99/2.524 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        0.377 \\
        0.4837 \\
        -0.79 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
$$EigenvectorEstimation3=\begin{pmatrix}
        -0.18 & -0.61 & 0.84 \\
        -0.61 & -0.75 & 1.24 \\
        0.84 & 1.24 & -1.95 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
        0.377 \\
        0.4837 \\
        -0.79 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        -1.025 \\
        -1.567 \\
        2.45 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
$$EigenvalueEstimation3=\sqrt{(-1.025)^2+(-1.567)^2+2.45^2}=3.086$$

and so on...

It's second eigenvalue of initial matrix. But actually it's should be negative! How can I get that it's negative??? this algorithm gives only magnitude (without sign). How can I modify this?

Comment: I'd like to make gpgpu (openCL) implementation of this algorithm.
I use power iteration method described by Hagen von Eitzen just below this post

Comment: Given an approximate eigenvector (found by power iteration) it will approximately be multiplied by its eigenvalue when you apply the matrix. For the sign, just look whether it (approximately) flips direction or not.

Comment: Thank you! You're right. What about to get sign of eigenvalue by dividing EigenvectorEstimation(k+1)/EigenvectorNormalized(k) when algorithm already convergent? is it also correct???

Answer (score 2):

Dima Railguner;

If I remember correctly you can determine the sign of the dominant eigenvalue by observing the xn and the xn+1 iteration. The signs will alternate when the dominant eigenvalue is negative and won't when it is positive. That is at least what some books say.

Also, my power method gets -3.09... So for at least this problem it does not have a problem with the signs.

Looks like we are not using the same method. I can give you a link to mine if you want it.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. And how you get -3.09??? Look at my post (I updated it). What I do wrong?

Comment: would appreciate

Comment: @DimaRailguner in the algorithm you are using squaring, adding and then taking the square root is what is destroying the signs.

Comment: I know. And that is problem. But what about to get sign of eigenvalue by dividing EigenvectorEstimation(k+1)/EigenvectorNormalized(k) when algorithm already convergent? is it correctly???

Comment: @DimaRailguner I do not know about that. I have a correction for the link which provides a simpler approach that I think preserves the signs.http://www.math.tamu.edu/~dallen/linear_algebra/chpt6.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The eigen-value should be updated by $\mathbf{V}^H \mathbf{A} \mathbf{V}$, where $\mathbf{V} = \begin{pmatrix}
        0.377 \\
        0.4837 \\
        -0.79 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ is the estimated eigenvector and $\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix}
        -0.18 & -0.61 & 0.84 \\
        -0.61 & -0.75 & 1.24 \\
        0.84 & 1.24 & -1.95 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ is the residue matrix. Then, you can get negative eigenvalues.

$\begin{pmatrix}
        0.377 \\
        0.4837 \\
        -0.79 \\
        \end{pmatrix}^H \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
        -0.18 & -0.61 & 0.84 \\
        -0.61 & -0.75 & 1.24 \\
        0.84 & 1.24 & -1.95 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
        0.377 \\
        0.4837 \\
        -0.79 \\
        \end{pmatrix}= -3.0885$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your method is to start with a "random" vector $v_0$ and let $v_{n+1}=\frac{Av_n}{\|Av_n\|}$. Then $v_n$ will converge to a (normed) eigenvector of the (absolutely) largest eigenvalue. Since $Av_n\approx \lambda v_n$, you can obtain an approximation from any nonzero component of $v_n$ (for numerical reasons, pick the component with largest absolute value).

Are you aware that iterating with $(A-\tilde\lambda)^{-1}$ instead of $A$, where $\tilde\lambda$ is an estimation for the largest eigenvalue (obtained e.g. from the first few iteratiosn above), may speed up convergence?

Comment: Thank you very much. But anyway, how to determine sign of eigenvalue???

Comment: And what about complexity of iterating with inverse matrix (Inverse Power method)? it's O(n^3). but power iteration method has O(n^2) (by one step). So is it still profitable to use Inverse Power method? I think no. Correct me if I wrong.